# What is Returned in Ruby if the Last Statement Evaluated is an If Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, return

My understanding is that ruby returns the last statement evaluated in a function.  What if the function ends with an `if` statement that evaluates to false

```
def thing(input)
  item = input == "hi"
  if item
    []
  end
end

puts thing("hi").class #> Array
puts thing("not hi").class #> NilClass
```

I like this functionality (returning `nil` if the statement is false), but why isn't `false` returned (from the assignment to `item`)?

Comment: Maybe it is because of missing `else` statement. So missing `else` mean it is `nil`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*If your `if` statement doesn't result in any code being run, it returns `nil`*, otherwise it returns the value of the code that was run. `irb` is a good tool to experiment with such stuff:

```
irb(main):001:0> i = if false then end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> i = if true then end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> i = if false then "a" end
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> i = if false then "a" else "b" end
=> "b"
```

Answer (score 6):

The return value of an `if` expression is the value of the clause that was evaluated, not of the condition. *In case no clause was evaluated (`if` without `else`), `nil` is returned*:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = if false
irb(main):002:1> []
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> x
=> nil
irb(main):005:0>
```