# Ruby's variable equals if variable equals method?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am reading through [createyourlang](http://createyourproglang.com/) book and saw a code snippet that looks like this:

```
  tokenizer = if identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]
                IdentifierTokenizer.new(identifier, tokenizer).tokenize
              elsif constant = chunk[CONSTANT, 1]
                ConstantTokenizer.new(constant, tokenizer).tokenize
              elsif number = chunk[NUMBER, 1]
                ...
```

I find it confusing having two equal signs on the same line. What does it mean to have `A = if B = C`?

*If you're wondering what chunk is, assume chunk is string `"hello"` and `chunk[IDENTIFIER,1]` equals to `"hello"` and the other `chunk[OTHER_CONST,1]` equals to `nil`. The function works. You can find the source code repo [here](https://github.com/IggHub/awesome-lang/blob/master/lexer/lexer.rb).* I am mainly curious how to read this function/ if there is a better way to rewrite this code to make it more readable?

Comment: `if` (and everything else) is an expression in Ruby. See… https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061572/707111, I guess? Anyway, once you’re familiar with this concept that applies to Ruby, it’ll be readable.

Comment: Assignment is also an expression so `if identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]` is equivalent to `identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]; if identifier`.

Comment: `==` tests for equality, `=` is an assignment operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be confusing, in part because one's first reaction to seeing `if identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]` may be that it's probably a bug, that the author meant `if identifier == chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]`.

The code block given in the question is probably equivalent to:

```
tokenizer =
  if chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]
    IdentifierTokenizer.new(chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1], tokenizer).tokenize
  elsif chunk[CONSTANT, 1]
    ConstantTokenizer.new(chunk[CONSTANT, 1], tokenizer).tokenize
  elsif chunk[NUMBER, 1]
    NumberTokenizer.new(chunk[NUMBER, 1], tokenizer).tokenize
  ..
```

Rather than computing `chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1]`, `chunk[CONSTANT, 1]` and `chunk[NUMBER, 1]` twice, those values are assigned to variables (`identifier`, `constant`, `number`) the first time they are calculated. (Those assignments are evaluated before `if` and `elsif` are applied.) This is commonly done when such calculations are costly or have an undesired side effect when performed more than once. The use of temporary variables in this way also [DRYs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the code, but other approaches that achieve the same objective may be preferable. I personally avoid such inline variable assignments, in part because I regard them as ugly.

One alternative that may be more clear, and which DRYs the code even more, is the following.

```
tokenizer =
  tokenit(IDENTIFIER, IdentifierTokenize, tokenizer) ||
  tokenit(CONSTANT,   ConstantTokenize,   tokenizer) ||
  tokenit(NUMBER,     NumberTokenize,     tokenizer) ||
  ...

def tokenit(type, class, tokenizer)
  ch = chunk[type, 1]
  if ch
    class.public_send(:new, ch, tokenizer).tokenize
  else
    false
  end
end
```

This of course assumes that when `ch` is truthy `class.public_send(:new, ch, tokenizer).tokenize` is also truthy.

Comment: A common way to indicate that the assignment is intended is to wrap it in parentheses, i.e. `if (identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1])`

Comment: @Stefan, of course readers unfamiliar with that hint may conclude that the author didn't need the parentheses as well as having intended to write `==`. Perhaps we need a convention that hits the reader over the head: `(((identifier = chunk[IDENTIFIER, 1])))`. (Yes, your suggestion is a good one.)